# TOAD 12.6 Data Grid doesn't display all rows in the result set (vs TOAD 10.6)

Tags: toad

Switching from TOAD 10.6 to TOAD 12.6 and having an issue with the Data Grid display.  It seems that only a limited number of rows can be viewed in the new version.  Here is what it looks like in 10.6 (by the way, please ignore the counts - these are 2 different employee databases - the first has 8 rows returned - the second has only 7):

[image: 10.6 Data Grid]

Here is what it looks like in 12.6 (two images).  Only 6 rows are displayed:

[image: 12.6 Data Grid Part 1]

The data grid is limited to 6 rows being displayed and then it can be scrolled down, but not all can be viewed at once even though there is room on the screen below.

Here is the entire grid after scrolling down.

[image: 12.6 Data Grid Part 2]

There is no place to drag this larger, no maximize the window, and I can't find anything in View --> Toad Options --> Data Grids --> Visual.  Here is the options screen and I've tried pretty much every button in desperation:

[image: Toad Options]

Does someone have a way of expanding the view to see more rows?  (And as you can tell, I'm not talking about the 500 row return limitation - I would like to see as many rows as it takes to fill the entire screen and not just view useless grey space).

Comment: I'm on 12.6.0.53 with the same settings you show and it works for me. What if you drag the top of the data grid pane up or down to adjust, does the bottom of the screen resize?

Comment: Right-click on the data grid title bar and select "restore default desktop".  Did that help?  Just in case a configuration change got locked in by accident?  Maybe try unpinning, then repinning the data grid window (click on the pushpin to the extreme right of the title bar)?

Comment: Thank You!!!!  Restore Default Desktop was the answer - will you post that as an official answer so I can mark it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try right-clicking on the data grid title bar and select "restore default desktop".  Perhaps a configuration change got locked in by accident and this should reset it.